# How to cancel profile deletion?

Tags: support, users, deleted-users

Yesterday, I went through the process of cancelling my profile.

This morning I received a message where it said I should click a button to confirm the deletion. I've since changed my mind and I want to remain a member.

How can I cancel the deletion of my profile?

For the moment, I've just changed the *please delete me* phrase to something else.

Is that enough or will I be erased as a file to the dustbin?

Comment: Your last sentence made me smile. If you're  that funny we're looking forward to more of your contributions.

Comment: Goodbye OP. You didn't stay after all. :(

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you did not confirm the deletion and you removed the *please delete me* message from your profile, the deletion process will automatically be cancelled. You don't have to do anything else.

Glad to have you stay with us!